# Need to replace only select values on particular line in text file

Tags: string, perl, text-files, substitution

pretty new to perl and am simply trying to modify the values on a particular line in a text file.  The line reads:

```
  1.0040      1.0033      1.0021      0.9997      0.9997      0.9997
```

I'd like to substitute 1.0000 for any values less than 1 but still keep all the values originally 1 or greater and keep all digits in their "original" places in the text file (including modified ones). Sometimes visual checks are needed and it makes it easier if everything is in the same place in modified files. New line should read:

```
  1.0040      1.0033      1.0021      1.0000      1.0000      1.0000
```

Can I do something along the lines of: 
      $_ =~ s/[SOME LOGIC TO ONLY REPLACE VALUES LESS THAN 1]/1.0000/g;
?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, not hard. The `/e` modifier lets you specify an expression whose result will be used as the replacement in `s///`. You can just put a conditional in there:

```
s {
  ([\d\.]+)                 # Given some floating-point number,
} {
  $1 < 1.0 ? "1.0000" : $1  # replace iff less than 1.0.
}xge;
```

Squashed:

```
s/([\d\.]+)/$1 < 1 ? "1.0000" : $1/ge
```

If you end up needing more complex replacement logic, you can also use e.g. `sprintf("%1.4f", $x)` to get a particular floating-point number format.